# JAva Decompiler (JAD) - Do not output a class name with slashes

Tags: jad

When I'm using the GUI edition, it's shown as

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, Someclass.class);
```

But in console mode with parameters

```
jad -o -r -b -f -sjava Someclass.class
```

It's outputed as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com/example/Someclass);
```

Is there a way to output it as in gui mode? I don't see any appropriate parameter in documentation http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are decompiling Android application with out-of-date, stale, not-supported JAD.
Try a specialized decompiler, i.e. JADX.

Download it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jadx/files/ or use online service: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk